# How to close a stream event?

Tags: javascript-sdk, stream

I just opened a stream to listen for transactions. I'd like to know, how to close it, once I get what I am looking for. I can't find the close method in channel, or any of the objects for setting the channel to null, that would close it.

Sample code:

```
var channel = server.transactions()
    .forAccount(address)
    .cursor('now')
    .stream({ stuff });
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Call the returned object itself.

In your case: `channel();`

Answer (score 5):

As described in the docs, [`TransactionCallBuilder.stream`](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/TransactionCallBuilder_TransactionCallBuilder.html#stream) returns a function you can call to close a stream:

> Returns:
>
> Type:  function
>
> Close function. Run to close the connection and stop listening for new events.

Answer (score 2):

I am just trying to make it more clear for the future visitors,

[TransactionCallBuilder.stream](https://stellar.github.io/js-stellar-sdk/TransactionCallBuilder_TransactionCallBuilder.html#stream) returns the function to close the connection.

```
// Opens the stream channel
var streamChannel = server.transactions()
    .forAccount(address)
    .cursor('now')
    .stream({ stuff });

// Close the channel 
streamChannel()
```