# Can't close server stream

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk

The other existing question didn't work for me. ([How to close a stream event?](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/41/how-to-close-a-stream-event))

I set up a class to handle and switch streams. In the constructor, I define and initialize the stream this way:

```
function RequestStream() {

    this.server = new StellarSdk.Server('https://horizon.stellar.org');

    this.stream = this.server.transactions()
    .cursor('now')
    .stream({
      onmessage: function (message) {
        //console.log(message);
        console.log("initial transactions stream");
        tripManager.addTrip(new Trip(node2.position));
      }
    });
}
```

My instance variable stream should contain the function close to close the stream. Using a prototype, I have several functions to switch the stream. I want to close the current stream through the instance variable before creating a new one and setting it to the same instance variable.

```
RequestStream.prototype = {
   constructor: RequestStream,
      payments:function ()  {
        this.stream.close();
        this.stream = this.server.payments() // + rest of stream init
    } 
}
```

I receive "TypeError: this.stream.close is not a function" upon trying to close the stream. Printing out this.stream gives an object with no apparent useful info. Can provide more detail if needed.

Answer (score 2):

In your case `this.stream` after initialization should contain a destructor function. Try to call `this.stream()` instead of `this.stream.close()`.